# Getting memory error on training vectors over quora's datasets

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I am getting the following errors while extracting features of quora's dataset. I am using a 32 bit ubuntu system.

```
404290it [01:25, 4731.71it/s]
404290it [01:26, 4649.86it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "feature_engineering.py", line 96, in 
    data['cosine_distance'] = [cosine(x, y) for (x, y) in zip(np.nan_to_num(question1_vectors),
  File "/home/karan/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 385, in nan_to_num
    x = _nx.array(x, subok=True, copy=copy)
MemoryError
```

Comment: It means that the memory buffer on your machine cannot hold so much data. Waht's the shape of the Quora dataset?

Comment: Actually I come to know that the machine is holding the buffer fine but the moment np.nan_to_num(q1,q2) is done then it gives Memory error. Any suggestion to avoid this?

Comment: Edit your question with some data